# Interpreting ccf() plot in R

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

I was hoping you could help me interpret the following cross-correlation plot of U.S. and China short-term interest rate time series(1997-2015). I am a beginner to statistics, so I apologize if I am making simple mistakes.

Would it be correct to say that since a lag of 4-5 months will yield a correlation of just shy of -0.3, which is past the dotted line (is that the 5% chance of randomness demarcation?), I can say that this lag will give us a statically significant correlation?

I doubt this is true (4-5 month lag seems very arbitrary), but I'm not sure what the correct interpretation would be.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Asking for help with interpretation of results from statistical models isn't really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about statistical models, you should ask over at [stats.se].

Comment: Ah, my apologies.